# ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Hi my docker image build throws up the following error

```
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
------

 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
------
 > [internal] load .dockerignore:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to create lease: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.5
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY app.py .
COPY main.py .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I have tried many solutions but nothing works. Any idea how to resolve this isse?

Comment: What have you done? OMG! You've broken it!!! ;) It looks like your docker installation is screwed up somehow. Key docker directories are read-only. I'd try to erase and reinstall docker. But, it would help us advise you more accurately if you could tell us something about your environment. OS, processor architecture, version of docker, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error
failed to solve the frontend docker file.v0: was unable to read docker file: failed to create lease: read-only file system

**Solution:**

1. I just stopped the Docker desktop service and close the visual code.
2. Next I restart the laptop
3. then start the docker desktop service
4. open Vscode and run the docker build command (docker build -t "image name" . (don't miss the last dot)

Finally, It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker : #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
```

I had this same issue when trying to build a Dockerfile from Windows Powershell ISE as I was working on a script. When I actually opened a Powershell *shell* and ran the same script then everything worked fine.