# ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: failed to create lease: read-only file system

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am unable to create a build with this command:
`docker build -t feedback-node .`
Although docker was working fine previously.
I have also tried almost all the available suggestions but found nothing that could resolve it.
[image: This is the snapshot of it]

I was trying to build an image with the tag feedback-node and was expecting the id of the image after build.
This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

# .represents the current directory
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468409/error-internal-load-build-definition-from-dockerfile#answer-76010037), might be related to the PowerShell usage ? If you are on Windows, the common usage is WSL2

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it worked. Actually I couldn't find the entitled same problem on stack overflow though I had tried to do so.